# how to establish the RegionServer of Hbase to master

Tags: hadoop, hbase

Please tell me how to establish the RegionServer of Hbase to master.
I configured 5 region servers, however, only 2 server is worked properly.

---

hbase(main):001:0> status
2 servers, 0 dead, 1.5000 average load

---

The hostname of this two servers are sm3-10 and sm3-12 from http://hbase-master:60010.
But the other servers like sm3-8 not work.

I'd like to know the trouble shooting step and resolutions.

sm3-10:slave, work well

---

[root@sm3-10 ~]# jps
2581 QuorumPeerMain
2761 SecondaryNameNode
2678 DataNode
19913 Jps
2551 HRegionServer
[root@sm3-10 ~]# lsof -i:54310
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE NODE NAME
java    2678 hdfs   52r  IPv6  27608       TCP sm3-10:33316->sm3-12:54310 (ESTABLISHED)
[root@sm3-10 ~]# lsof -i:3888
COMMAND  PID      USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE NODE NAME
java    2581 zookeeper   19u  IPv6   7239       TCP *:ciphire-serv (LISTEN)
java    2581 zookeeper   20u  IPv6   7242       TCP sm3-10:ciphire-serv->sm3-11:53593 (ESTABLISHED)
java    2581 zookeeper   25u  IPv6  27011       TCP sm3-10:ciphire-serv->sm3-12:40352 (ESTABLISHED)
java    2581 zookeeper   29u  IPv6  25573       TCP sm3-10:ciphire-serv->sm3-8:44271 (ESTABLISHED)

---

sm3-8:slave, not work properly, however, the status looks good

---

[root@sm3-8 ~]# jps
3489 Jps
2249 HRegionServer
2463 DataNode
2297 QuorumPeerMain
2686 SecondaryNameNode
[root@sm3-8 ~]# lsof -i:54310
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE NODE NAME
java    2463 hdfs   51u  IPv6   9919       TCP sm3-8.nos-seamicro.local:40776->sm3-12:54310 (ESTABLISHED)
[root@sm3-8 ~]# lsof -i:3888
COMMAND  PID      USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE NODE NAME
java    2297 zookeeper   18u  IPv6   5951       TCP *:ciphire-serv (LISTEN)
java    2297 zookeeper   19u  IPv6   9839       TCP sm3-8.nos-seamicro.local:52886->sm3-12:ciphire-serv (ESTABLISHED)
java    2297 zookeeper   20u  IPv6   5956       TCP sm3-8.nos-seamicro.local:44271->sm3-10:ciphire-serv (ESTABLISHED)
java    2297 zookeeper   24u  IPv6   5959       TCP sm3-8.nos-seamicro.local:47922->sm3-11:ciphire-serv (ESTABLISHED)

---

Mastet:sm3-12

---

[root@sm3-12 ~]# jps
2760 QuorumPeerMain
3035 NameNode
3096 SecondaryNameNode
2612 HRegionServer
4330 Jps
2872 DataNode
3723 HMaster
[root@sm3-12 ~]# lsof -i:54310
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE NODE NAME
java    2872 hdfs   51u  IPv6   7824       TCP sm3-12:45482->sm3-12:54310 (ESTABLISHED)
java    3035 hdfs   54u  IPv6   7783       TCP sm3-12:54310 (LISTEN)
java    3035 hdfs   70u  IPv6   7873       TCP sm3-12:54310->sm3-8:40776 (ESTABLISHED)
java    3035 hdfs   71u  IPv6   7874       TCP sm3-12:54310->sm3-11:54990 (ESTABLISHED)
java    3035 hdfs   72u  IPv6   7875       TCP sm3-12:54310->sm3-10:33316 (ESTABLISHED)
java    3035 hdfs   74u  IPv6   7877       TCP sm3-12:54310->sm3-12:45482 (ESTABLISHED)
[root@sm3-12 ~]#
[root@sm3-12 ~]# cat /etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml





hbase.rootdir
hdfs://sm3-12:54310/hbase
true



hbase.zookeeper.quorum
sm3-8,sm3-10,sm3-11,sm3-12,sm3-13
true

     --- snip  ---

[root@sm3-12 ~]# cat /etc/zookeeper/zoo.cfg
tickTime=2000
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
dataDir=/var/zookeeper
clientPort=2181
server.1=sm3-10:2888:3888
server.2=sm3-11:2888:3888
server.3=sm3-12:2888:3888
server.4=sm3-8:2888:3888
[root@sm3-12 ~]#

---

Thanks in advance,

Hiromi

Comment: Please remove the JPS stuff that is totally unhelpful. Look in your logs and post some exceptions or post your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

check to make sure your dns is configured properly on all of the hosts, and each server can do a reverse lookup

Comment: I appreciate the comment. I fond the miss-configuration of hbase-site.xml on HRegionServer and ClockOutOfSyncException. It work properly after sync the time.

Comment: Nice catch.  One critical element for hadoop clusters is sync'ed time via ntp or something equivalent.  If you don't have ntp running, servers will slowly move out of sync and you will start to get weird errors